# Django user.is_authenticated via ajax works in WebKit but not Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, http, firefox

I'm sending a cross-domain jsonp request to /isauthenticated, which routes to a function that returns user.is_authenticated (0 or 1). It works great in WebKit, but returns 0 every time in Firefox 5-7, even when I'm clearly logged in. If I copy the url that ajax sends (including ?callback=callback) and paste it in the browser, it works as it should.

Do I need different headers or something for Firefox ajax?

Here's my ajax call right now.

```
$.ajax({
    url: domain + '/account/isauthenticated/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
       if(data === 0) {
          //Not logged in, every time in Firefox
       } else if(data == 1) {
          //logged in
       }
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header? What is the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? What cookies are being sent? On OSX you can get this data by typing cmd+shift+k in firefox before making the request, then clicking the request.

Comment: Those headers aren't present and it doesn't show any cookies being sent. In WebKit, it shows cookies being sent but neither of those headers. Any thoughts? Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd party cookies were being blocked in the browser settings. Duh.